# ExtJS - How to get DOM ID of a component?

Tags: extjs

Say the component doesnt have an ID given to it. So how would you first, get a handle on the component, and then get the DOM Id of that component?

thanks in advance!

-Jack

Comment: Have you [checked this out](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/element.html)?

Comment: Why do you want the DOM id of the component?

Answer (score 1):

Use the javascript console. You can also install FireBug.

In your javascript code put:

```
 console.log(myComponentWhosIdIWantToGet);
```

Explore you object's properties.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you need: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getEl

Example:

```
//get Dom Element
var DomEl = Ext.getCmp('ComponentID').getEl();
//get Id
var DomElId = DomEl.id;
```

Comment: `getEl` returns an Ext.Element, so to get the `dom` you'd want `.getEl().dom;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (not so many distinctions from answer of Meister but anyway):

```
var DomEl = Ext.getCmp('ComponentID').getEl().dom.id;
```