# extjs function change href value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I made the following function with extjs that change the clicked Href and the last part:

```
document.getElementById("#device").href = url;
```

is not working.
I tried with extjs function get to select and change my href ... but same result.
Any solution or other way to do this ?

```
Ext.select('#tab-home-view ul li a').on('click', function (ev) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.replace("http://localhost:8080", "");
    Ext.select('#tab-home-view ul li').removeCls('active');
    Ext.get(ev.currentTarget).up('li').addCls('active');
    var current = Ext.get(ev.currentTarget).getAttribute('href');
    url = url + current;
    document.getElementById("#device").href = url;
});
```

my tabs :

```
<div class="tabs" id="tab-home-view">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li id="General" class="active"><a href="&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=0">General</a></li>
    <li id="device"><a href="&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=1">Device</a></li>
    <li id="link"><a href="&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=2">Link</a></li>
    <li id="Service"><a href="&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=3">Service</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.get()` obtains an ext element.

You need to use the property `dom` on the element to modify the `href`.  However, `div` is also the *parent* of the `a` element; so you need to go `down` to the `<a>`.

You could modify the href with the following:

`Ext.get('device').down('a').dom.href = '/newhref';`

[Here is fiddle demonstrating](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nbg)

Comment: I finally choose another way to do my stuff but thank you for your answer that should be the good one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the #:

```
document.getElementById("device").href = url;
```

That's regular JavaScript syntax. I'm not really familiar with extjs, so I don't know what else I would try. Maybe this could help: [ExtJS - How to get DOM ID of a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253834/extjs-how-to-get-dom-id-of-a-component)

Comment: I tried to replace it by Ext.get(ev.currentTarget).getAttribute('href') = url; but same result